# How should I do if I am going to define a model called User in loopbackjs from an api-server application?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I created an api-server loopbackjs application and I want to define a model called **User** having *completely different properties with the built-in one*. So when I run `slc loopback:model`, it throws an error as below.

```
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ValidationError: The `ModelDefinition` instance is not valid. Details: `name` is not unique (value: "User").
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:326:12
    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:511:13)
    at ModelConstructor.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:82:12)
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:508:25)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:586:7
    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:380:5)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1985:11
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:396:17
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:393:21
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1962:17
    at doNotify (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:99:49)
    at doNotify (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:99:49)
    at doNotify (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:99:49)
    at doNotify (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:99:49)
```

I'd really appreciate that anyone can shed a light on this issue if I really need a model called **User** in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loopback comes with some built-in models;-) User is one of them.
name your model in lowercase(user).

it's better that your user model inherit from the loopback's User model because there are lots of implemented functionalities you may need.

Comment: Name my model **user** in lowercase can make it be created, however when it comes to sending request to the api end point, it is going to be conflicted with the built-in one.

Comment: Haven't checked that. But it won't be a problem if it inherits from the User.

Comment: so if I get my **user** model inherits from **User**, can I remove these unnecessary properties?

Comment: What unnecessary properties?

Comment: The built-in **User** model have properties like **password**, **email**, etc. I don't need these.

Comment: Some of these properties are required and by making changes to them you may come up with some other problems. I think , in your case, it is better to name your 'user' model with other name such as "myuser".

Comment: @kenshinji: If you hide the built-in `User` model in `model-config.json` it won't cause conflicts as long as you make sure that internally you always use `user` over `User`. Since you don't want to use password, email and other built-in user management features, are you sure you need to extend the built-in `User` model? Maybe `PersistedModel` is enough for you.

Comment: Good to know:-)